# ヘルプセンターの「Markdown 編集ヘルプ」で表示が崩れている箇所がある

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

[Markdown 編集ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ページにおける「インデントによるコードブロック」の表示結果が一部崩れてしまっています。

---

**日本語版での表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**英語版での表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 他の国際サイトでも同様の問題が発生しているようなので、MSE でも改めて報告しておきました。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

修正が以下の通り反映されたことを確認済みです。

**現在の表示:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]